# JPA Native Query shuffling UUID binaries on native MSSQL insert

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to execute the following query in JPA via a native query with my MSSQL DB:

```
@Modifying
@Query(
       value = "update dbName.DQM set OverallScore= :overallScore, " +
                "CompletenessScore= :completenessScore, UniquenessScore= :uniquenessScore " +
                "where ColumnId = :columnId " +
                "IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 " +
                "insert into dbName.DQM (Id, DataSourceId, DatabaseId, TableId, ColumnId, OverallScore, " +
                "CompletenessScore, UniquenessScore, Version, CreatedBy, CreateDT) " +
                "values( " +
                "NEWID(), " +
                ":datasourceId, " +
                ":databaseId, " +
                ":tableId, " +
                ":columnId, " +
                ":overallScore, " +
                ":completenessScore, " +
                ":uniquenessScore, " +
                ":version, " +
                ":createdBy, " +
                "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP " +
                ")",
        nativeQuery = true
)
void upsertDQM(UUID datasourceId, UUID databaseId, UUID tableId, UUID columnId, double overallScore, double completenessScore, double uniquenessScore, long version, UUID createdBy);
```

And when passing the UUID, the binaries get switched up. An example of this would be if I pass in UUID 1 as a @PathVariable. It will register in the service method BEFORE saving in the insert as it's appropriate value, '0a0303d8-e816-6c44-9aca-a0204a07a9e1'. However, after inserting, it saved into the database as UUID 2. And UUID 1 and UUID 2 have the same binaries in a switched order, as shown/displayed below:

UUID 1 ==> 0a0303d8-e816-6c44-9aca-a0204a07a9e1

UUID 2 ==> d803030a-16e8-446c-9aca-a0204a07a9e1

---

The last part is the exact same ---> -9aca-a0204a07a9e1

And the first part of each:

0a --> 03 --> 03 -->d8 | e8 --> 16 | 6c --> 44

d8 --> 03 --> 03 -->0a | 16 --> e8 | 44 --> 6c

When I change the type from UUID to a String in Java, it saves appropriately in MSSQL as the correct uniqueidentifier so I do have an alright workaround, but I could not find in google a solid reason as to why this is happening. Has anyone ever ran into this or does anyone know why JPA or a native query would behave this way? Thank you for your time